# Integrating Microsoft Bot with Sharepoint using OAuth Node js

Tags: node.js, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, botframework

I'm referring to [this blog post](http://thecollaborationcorner.com/2017/01/25/search-for-your-sharepoint-content-from-a-bot-using-the-bot-framework-oauth2-and-node-js/#.WS5v5Ot96es) for integrating Microsoft Bot with Sharepoint using OAuth node js

We are getting the below error once we click on the sign in button, we are getting the error.

[image]

Thanks
Anu

Comment: Hello Anu. I think it is a bit difficult to recreate your issue. Could you try to isolate your question into a narrower situation somehow?

Comment: Hi, we have followed all the steps that are in the blog, but when you run the bot emulator to test it will ask me to sign in , once i click on the sign in button. it will redirect me to the error page as mentioned above.

Comment: Per the error, it seems you reply url is not valid. What URL did you add there?

Comment: @EzequielJadib we used the ngrok directory URL as redirect URI

Comment: it seems the URL you added is wrong, double check. the issue is clear, the URL must be a valid absolute uri

Comment: @EzequielJadib we have added the URL as per the blog post... If you could specify what URL we are supposed to add it would be helpful

Comment: Have you configured the reply/redirect URI in both parts? Azure and Node.js config?

Comment: @EzequielJadib we have configured at both the ends

Comment: Is ngrok running and did you use the HTTPS endpoint? if you navigate to the ngrok url, what happens?

Comment: Yes, we have used HTTPS endpoint. when we hit the ngrok url directly w eare getting "{"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"GET is not allowed"}"

Comment: yes expected because it's an API. can you copy the URL of the page with the error?

Comment: @EzequielJadib URL: https://cb1753b7.ngrok.io/api/oauthcallback ERROR: {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"GET is not allowed"}

Comment: The URL of the browser where do you get the error: login.microsoft...

Comment: https://login.microsoft.com/93f33571-550f-43cf-b09f-cd331338d086/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=25fd0f60-5a60-4274-be26-bd48784f6f44&state=%7B%22id%22%3A%22ckebi2khg5g258m0i%22%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22emulator%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22default-user%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22User%22%7D%2C%22conversation%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22n898i2bm0fml7db09%22%7D%2C%22bot%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22default-bot%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Bot%22%7D%2C%22serviceUrl%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A4816%22%7D&resource=&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=undefined

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provide, it doesn't contain a validated `redrect_uri`(redirect_uri=undefined), please double check this parameter has been config in the `launch.json` like the link mentioned:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Lancer le programme",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\server.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env":{
                "REDIRECT_URI": "https://0dd92b8d.ngrok.io/api/oauthcallback"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Yes, we have made the changes as specified in the blog. here is a sample code
`"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Lancer le programme",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\server.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env":{
                "REDIRECT_URI": "https://ecf26c19.ngrok.io/api/oauthcallback",
               
            }
`

Comment: So what's the `adalConfig` you have config? I also suggest that you debug the code to set the break endpoint for the line of `adalConfig.templateAuthzUrl =  adalConfig.authorityUrl...` in the `server.js `file to verify whether the redirect_uri was set correctly.

Comment: now we are facing this issue: 


AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '25ff44XXXXX'' was not found in the directory 93f33571XXXXX'

Comment: It seems that you were sign-in the application using the account not in the tenant which you register the app. If you expect this behavior you can enable the **Multi-tenanted** feature for the application on the Azure portal.